# TinyGps No data

Tags: gps, arduino, location, tracking

I'm working on a tracking project. I'm using TinyDuino Processor Bd together with TinyGPS shield. Just to test the GPS shield, I have tried all possible codes using the libraries TinyGPS and TinyGPS++. they all failed and gave me an output of 0's or uninterpretable output. here are some codes I tried with there output. 
Code 1:
        #include

```
    static const int GPS_ONOFFPin = A3;
    static const int GPS_SYSONPin = A2;
    static const int GPS_RXPin = A1;
    static const int GPS_TXPin = A0;
    static const int GPSBaud = 9600;
    static const int chipSelect = 10;

    // The GPS connection is attached with a software serial port
    SoftwareSerial Gps_serial(GPS_RXPin, GPS_TXPin);

    int led = 13;

    void setup()
    {  
    // Init the GPS Module to wake mode
    pinMode(GPS_SYSONPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(GPS_ONOFFPin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite( GPS_ONOFFPin, LOW );   
    delay(5); 
    if( digitalRead( GPS_SYSONPin ) == LOW )
    {
         // Need to wake the module
        digitalWrite( GPS_ONOFFPin, HIGH ); 
        delay(5); 
        digitalWrite( GPS_ONOFFPin, LOW );      
     } 

      // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
      Serial.begin(9600);   
      pinMode(led, OUTPUT);    
     Gps_serial.begin(9600);
    }

    void loop()
    {
      if (Gps_serial.available())
          Serial.write(Gps_serial.read());
    }
```

[image: Code 1 output:]

Second Code:
        #include 
        #include

```
    /* This sample code demonstrates the normal use of a TinyGPS object.
       It requires the use of SoftwareSerial, and assumes that you have a
       4800-baud serial GPS device hooked up on pins 4(rx) and 3(tx).
    */

    TinyGPS gps;
     SoftwareSerial ss(4, 3);

    static void smartdelay(unsigned long ms);
    static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec);
    static void print_int(unsigned long val, unsigned long invalid, int len);
    static void print_date(TinyGPS &gps);
    static void print_str(const char *str, int len);

    void setup()
    {
      Serial.begin(115200);

      Serial.print("Testing TinyGPS library v. ");                

    Serial.println(TinyGPS::library_version());
      Serial.println("by Mikal Hart");
      Serial.println();
      Serial.println("Sats HDOP Latitude  Longitude  Fix  Date       Time        

    Date Alt    Course Speed Card  Distance Course Card  Chars Sentences   

    Checksum");
      Serial.println("          (deg)     (deg)      Age                         

    Age  (m)    --- from GPS ----  ---- to London  ----  RX    RX         
    Fail");
      Serial.println("--------------------------------------------------------   
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    ---");

      ss.begin(4800);
    }

    void loop()
    {
      float flat, flon;
      unsigned long age, date, time, chars = 0;
      unsigned short sentences = 0, failed = 0;
      static const double LONDON_LAT = 51.508131, LONDON_LON = -0.128002;

      print_int(gps.satellites(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_SATELLITES, 5);
      print_int(gps.hdop(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_HDOP, 5);
      gps.f_get_position(&flat, &flon, &age);
      print_float(flat, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 10, 6);
      print_float(flon, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 11, 6);
      print_int(age, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE, 5);
      print_date(gps);
      print_float(gps.f_altitude(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ALTITUDE, 7, 2);
      print_float(gps.f_course(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 7, 2);
      print_float(gps.f_speed_kmph(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_SPEED, 6, 2);
      print_str(gps.f_course() == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? "*** " :         TinyGPS::cardinal(gps.f_course()), 6);
      print_int(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? 0xFFFFFFFF : (unsigned long)TinyGPS::distance_between(flat, flon, LONDON_LAT, LONDON_LON) / 1000, 0xFFFFFFFF, 9);
      print_float(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE         : TinyGPS::course_to(flat, flon, LONDON_LAT, LONDON_LON),         TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 7, 2);
      print_str(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? "*** " :         TinyGPS::cardinal(TinyGPS::course_to(flat, flon, LONDON_LAT, LONDON_LON)), 6);

      gps.stats(&chars, &sentences, &failed);
      print_int(chars, 0xFFFFFFFF, 6);
      print_int(sentences, 0xFFFFFFFF, 10);
      print_int(failed, 0xFFFFFFFF, 9);
      Serial.println();

              smartdelay(1000);
            }

    static void smartdelay(unsigned long ms)
    {
      unsigned long start = millis();
      do 
      {
        while (ss.available())
          gps.encode(ss.read());
      } while (millis() - start < ms);
    }

    static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec)
    {
      if (val == invalid)
      {
        while (len-- > 1)
          Serial.print('*');
        Serial.print(' ');
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.print(val, prec);
        int vi = abs((int)val);
        int flen = prec + (val < 0.0 ? 2 : 1); // . and -
        flen += vi >= 1000 ? 4 : vi >= 100 ? 3 : vi >= 10 ? 2 : 1;
        for (int i=flen; i<len; ++i)
          Serial.print(' ');
              }
              smartdelay(0);
            }

    static void print_int(unsigned long val, unsigned long invalid, int len)
    {
      char sz[32];
      if (val == invalid)
        strcpy(sz, "*******");
      else
        sprintf(sz, "%ld", val);
      sz[len] = 0;
      for (int i=strlen(sz); i<len; ++i)
        sz[i] = ' ';
      if (len > 0) 
        sz[len-1] = ' ';
      Serial.print(sz);
      smartdelay(0);
    }

    static void print_date(TinyGPS &gps)
    {
      int year;
      byte month, day, hour, minute, second, hundredths;
      unsigned long age;
      gps.crack_datetime(&year, &month, &day, &hour, &minute, &second, &hundredths,         &age);
      if (age == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE)
        Serial.print("********** ******** ");
      else
      {
        char sz[32];
        sprintf(sz, "%02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d ",
            month, day, year, hour, minute, second);
        Serial.print(sz);
      }
      print_int(age, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE, 5);
      smartdelay(0);
    }

    static void print_str(const char *str, int len)
    {
      int slen = strlen(str);
      for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
        Serial.print(i<slen ? str[i] : ' ');
      smartdelay(0);
    }
```

[image: Code 2 Output:]

Comment: One problem that might occur: go out in the open to get satellite signals for your sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Code 1 confirms that the GPS device is working on A0/A1 at 9600 baud.  The /dev/cu.usbserial-DN00CT3C window shows good NMEA sentences being echoed.  But it doesn't have good satellite reception...  all the fields are zero value or empty.

Code 2 shows that the TinyGPS example is not receiving any characters.  That's because it's trying to use `SoftwareSerial` on pins 4 & 3.  Change it to

```
SoftwareSerial ss( A1, A0 );
```

You may also be interested in a more efficient library, [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS).  It can be configured to handle only the messages and fields that you use.  Everything else is ignored, saving RAM and processing time.

Answer (score 0):

The GPS TX pin goes to the Arduino RX piN and likewise, the GPS RX pin goes to the Arduino TX pin. For the Second code, the GPS Baudrate is given as 4800 in description. try with baudrate of 9600 in both serial.begin and ss.begin.

You probably have to be outside, or at least near some windows for the GPS device to receive from the satellites. It could take 15 minutes for the first fix to happen.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS.h>

TinyGPS gps;
SoftwareSerial ss(3,4);


static void smartdelay(unsigned long ms);
static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec);
static void print_int(unsigned long val, unsigned long invalid, int len);
static void print_date(TinyGPS &gps);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ss.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  float flat, flon;
  unsigned short sentences = 0, failed = 0;

  gps.f_get_position(&flat, &flon);

  Serial.print("LATITUDE: ");
  print_float(flat, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 10, 6);
  Serial.println(" ");

  Serial.print("LONGITUDE: "); 
  print_float(flon, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 11, 6);
  Serial.println(" ");

  Serial.print("altitude: ");
  print_float(gps.f_altitude(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ALTITUDE, 7, 2);
  Serial.println(" ");

  Serial.print("COURSE:");
  print_float(gps.f_course(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 7, 2);
  Serial.println("");

  Serial.print("DIRECTION: ");
  int d;
  print_str(gps.f_course() == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? "*** " : TinyGPS::cardinal(gps.f_course()), 6);
  d=gps.f_course(); 
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  smartdelay(1000);

}

static void smartdelay(unsigned long ms)
{
  unsigned long start = millis();
  do 
  {
    while (ss.available())
      int val = gps.encode(ss.read());
  } while (millis() - start < ms);
}

static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec)
{
  if (val == invalid)
  {
    while (len-- > 1)
      Serial.print('*');
    Serial.print(' ');
  }
  smartdelay(0);
}

static void print_str(const char *str, int len)
{
  int slen = strlen(str);
  for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
    Serial.print(i<slen ? str[i] : ' ');
  smartdelay(0);
}
```